# Django queries to retrieve specific attribute

Tags: python, django

```
max_shoots = player.objects.all().aggregate(Max('Num_baskets')['Num_baskets__max']
name1 = player.objects.get(Num_baskets=max_shoots)
return render(
    request,
    'index.html',
    context={'max_shoots':max_shoots, 'name':name1 },
)
```

Here player is our class name. we need to retrieve a specific attribute(eg:roll no. of a 'name1').could you please help me to solve it.using max_shoots that we already retrieved. I want to know Django query to retrieve above information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
player_obj = player.objects.order_by('-Num_baskets').first()
#do player_obj.roll_no
```